# How to display an object in angular returned from a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that returns an object.

```
public getLinkedTREsLevel() {
    let retval: any;
    if (this.entry && this.entry.config ) {
      this.entry.config.forEach( element => {
        if (element.name === 'creationTIme') {
          retval['dateLevel'] = element?.type?.label;
        }
        if (element.name === 'linkedTRE') {
          retval['treLevel'] = element?.type?.label;
        }
      });
      }
    return retval;
  }
```

I do not want to create a variable. In that case, is there any way that I could display this using angular?

That is how I was trying, but it says `treLevel` & `dateLevel` are undefined:

```
<div class="modal-title" >{{getLinkedTREsLevel()?.treLevel}}</div>
<div class="modal-title" >{{getLinkedTREsLevel()?.dateLevel}}</div>
```

Now without creating any extra object or variable how can I display this using angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can display json data using json pipe like this

```
<div class="modal-title" >{{getLinkedTREsLevel()?.treLevel | json}}</div>
<div class="modal-title" >{{getLinkedTREsLevel()?.dateLevel | json}}</div>
```

Here's the docs
https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe